# mysql - access json objects from a json data in mysql stored procedure

Tags: mysql, json, mysql-workbench

Would be great if someone provides me a hint to achieve this below scenario.

In my store procedure I have a select query which will output json data like
`{"1":"data1"},{"2":"data2"},{"3":"data3"},`.. so on

Now I need to fetch only first object `{"1":"data1"}` and then next `{"2":"data2"}` for further operations (am inserting this in one more table) .

So is there a way to get the objects one by one and also the length of this above json data

Comment: Have you read the docs for JSON functions in MySQL 5.7? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-functions.html

Comment: Also, that's not valid JSON. It appears to be an array, but you don't have `[]` around it. And each element is apparently an object, but does not have `"key":"value"` syntax. And you're using single-quotes but JSON supports only double-quotes. With all these mistakes, the JSON functions in MySQL won't work.

Comment: Sorry my bad !! Have edited my question. So if i get [] around my above json output will I be able to traverse my records and number of objects ?

Comment: Do any of the JSON functions in MySQL 5.7 do what you need to do? I linked to the doc above.

Comment: That really helped .. Thank you @BillKarwin

Comment: But dont see a way in json document to pass dynamic value in json_extract. say SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(@abcd, '$[0].element1'); returned me results. But is there a way i can make this 0 dynamic , i should have 1, 2 , 3 in that place

Answer (score 1):

I achieved this getting json_array from sql select and then accessing that using json_extract and using select concat to generate a runtime variable and then using that in json_extract. 
Thank you @billKarwin for the link to json documentation !!